# is Workflow Management right required to create SG with Workflow Process defined?

Tags: tridion

We are noticing that if a user without Workflow Management rights on a Publication tries to create a Structure Group and sets the "Associated Page Process" set on the Workflow tab, they get a permission error. If the workflow setting is removed, the user can save without issue.

I assume this is by design in the product, right? I wanted to verify that we weren't hitting something in our custom code. If it matters, here's what's logged:

Unable to save Structure Group (tcm:0-0-0). You do not have permission to perform this action. Error Code: 0x80040242 (-2147220926) Call stack: Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.AssertAccess(IdentifiableObjectData,Permissions,Rights) Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.StructureGroup.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs) Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs) Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save() Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObjectFacade.Create(UserContext,String) XMLState.Save StructureGroup.Save

thanks,

~Warner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to assign a Workflow Process Definition to an item (Schema or SG), you need Workflow Management rights.

Comment: thanks Chris for the quick answer. I figured as much. but, always good to double check the math :)